# Can you merge Managed Metadata Columns in a list?

Tags: list, managed-metadata, site-column

I have a two managed metadata site columns (I'm taking the Folksonomy approach). The first site column is called Presenters and contains names of individuals. The second site column is called Job Titles and contains titles of job positions.

In a new list I want to allow people to add multiple presenters and associate them with job titles. Such as:

Presenter1 JobTitle Description
Presenter2 JobTitle Description
Presenter3 JobTitle Description

I don't want to limit the number of presenters they can add to an item. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about Adding JobTitle and then adding multiple presenters to it? In other words JobTitle can have one-to-many Presenters.

Comment: I think this is to confusing.